# Kendo Treeview value selected from dropdown

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview, kendo-dropdown

Here I had a kendo dropdown and treeview. What I want to achieve if I select value from dropdown, value in treeview will be selected (as image below). Appreciate your help.

```js
  $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: [{ id:1, ledger: "Asset" }, 
      { id:2, ledger: "Current Asset" },
      { id:3, ledger: "Income" },
      { id:4, ledger: "Equity" },
      { id:5, ledger: "Sales" }], 
    dataTextField: "ledger",
    dataValueField: "id",
    select: onSelect
  });


  $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: [{ id:1, ledger: "Asset" }, 
      { id:2, ledger: "Current Asset" },
      { id:3, ledger: "Income" },
      { id:4, ledger: "Equity" },
      { id:5, ledger: "Sales" }],
    dataTextField: "ledger",
    dataValueField: "id"
  });


  function onSelect(e) {
    if (e.dataItem) {
      var dataItem = e.dataItem;
      console.log("select (" + dataItem.ledger + " : " + dataItem.id + ")");
    } 
  };
```

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/EyAziKUT)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/methods/select

```
function onSelect(e) {
if (e.dataItem) {
  var dataItem = e.dataItem;
  var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
  var bar = treeview.findByText(dataItem.ledger);
        treeview.select(bar);    
  console.log("select (" + dataItem.ledger + " : " + dataItem.id + ")");
}
```